# FreeBSD TCP/IP stack OR Linux TCP/IP stack

Tags: networking, tcp, freebsd

I was checking out the uIP (micro IP) IP stack, to figure out what porting a TCP/IP stack means.

I was wondering if there is a way we can cleanly remove only the TCP/IP stack from FreeBSD codebase and Linux codebase.

Is there some documentation about this? Is it as simple as just removing a couple of files and their respective Makefile components and building it or is it like copying just the code into personal project?

Any pointers would be really useful.

Comment: Edit: Can we remove the tcp/ip stack from FreeBSD and use it in user space in a Linux environment? Has anyone done it? Where does one start?

Comment: You can with the NetBSD stack, http://www.netbsd.org/docs/rump/ - you can run in userspace in Linux or other OS, or standalone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In many modern OSes the TCP/IP stack is *very* tightly integrated into the OS, or uses many core OS primitives (like memory allocation, synchronization, etc.) that it would be nearly impossible to "pull it out" into your own project (assuming embedded).  uIP and lwIP were written specifically for this purpose - using in your own custom environment without many ties to existing OS services.

Comment: Makes sense... So in effect, if we need to pull out FreeBSD stack, we need to pull that and everything else that stack code depends on.

Comment: @ChaitanyaH Correct. I've never looked at FreeBSD source, but I have looked at Linux, and I would rather quit programming forever than try and pull out just the TCP/IP stack into some custom (non-Linux) project.

Comment: Well, actually you can remove `INET` and `INET6` options from kernel config in FreeBSD. Not sure if the kernel would be buildable still.

Comment: @arrowdodger Right, I'm not saying that the kernel depends on the stack, I'm saying that the stack is dependent on the kernel "environment", have you.

Comment: I did some more digging and found this (dated) response - "Actually, not all *that* many, if you slice it out of the kernel along
just the right boundaries. [See below.]   "http://unix.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.unix.bsd.freebsd.misc/2007-07/msg00379.html

Comment: 25 years ago it took him two calendar months (probably around 350 hours) to do this. I'm sure the stack has grown since then. Good luck, and godspeed sir.